# Call both returns and calls action in a single MOCK_EXPECT

Tags: c++, turtle-mock

Can I call both returns and calls action at the same time in a single MOCK_EXPECT call? Like,

```
MOCK_EXPECT(a.method).calls(functor).returns(value);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The return value of the functor is the value that will be returned to the caller. Therefore giving an additional explicit return value via `.returns` makes little sense.

However you can still specify the return value at the expect call (as opposed to in the functor) by using a wrapper functor:

```
MOCK_EXPECT(a.method).calls([]() -> int {
    functor(); /* return value of functor is discarded */
    return 42; /* 42 is returned instead */
});
```